# undefined reference to `le16toh' error in Makefile

Tags: c, makefile, fat32

I'm trying to compile a C program with the following Makefile:

```
msh: libFAT32.so
    gcc -Wall -fPIC -I. -o msh newTest.c -L. -lFAT32

libFAT32.so: 
    gcc -std=c99 -shared -o libFAT32.so -fPIC fat32.c

clean: 
    rm *.so msh
```

However, every time I try to compile the program with make I get the following error:

```c
user@user-VirtualBox:~/fat1$ make
    gcc -Wall -fPIC -I. -o msh newTest.c -L. -lFAT32
    ./libFAT32.so: undefined reference to `le32toh'
    ./libFAT32.so: undefined reference to `le16toh'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    Makefile:19: recipe for target 'msh' failed
    make: *** [msh] Error 1
```

Can some one tell how to fix this?

Comment: Does the c/c++ code `#include <endian.h>`?  Typically those the functions it provides turn into inline code (or disappear entirely) so there isn't usually any external function to reference.

Comment: I did include endian.h

Comment: what is the gcc version?

Comment: `-I.` Did you `#include <endian.h>` or `#include "endian.h"` ? Is endian.h in your directory overwriting the default /usr/include/endian.h include? [`le32toh`](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/string/endian.h#L72) is probably a macro or at least an inline function, shouldn't be linked with. If not, maybe just write your own function, maybe `fat32.c` expects you to write it.

Comment: gcc version 7.3.0

Comment: I'm using #include <endian.h>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, here's what's going on (making the safe assumption that you're using a linux distribution in your VM).

With this test program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <endian.h>

int main(void) {
  printf("%d\n", le32toh(1234));
  return 0;
}
```

compiling and running it works:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra test.c
$ ./a.out
1234
```

However, you're compiling using `-std=c99`. So let's try that:

```
$ gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra test.c
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:5:18: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘le32toh’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   printf("%d\n", le32toh(1234));
                  ^~~~~~~
/tmp/cc7p3cO8.o: In function `main':
test.c:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `le32toh'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Compiling in `c99` mode disables a bunch of functions and macros and such that aren't in the 1999 version of the C standard unless they're explicitly requested, hence the implicit declaration warning. `le32toh()` is a macro, not a function with a symbol in libc, hence the linker error.

If you read the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/endian.3.html) for `le32toh()`, you'll see that it needs the `_DEFAULT_SOURCE` [feature test macro](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html), which must be defined before any headers are included.

So, your options are:

1. Compile in `gnu99` mode instead, since that automatically defines a bunch of the feature test macros.
2. Continue to use `c99` mode and add a `#define _DEFAULT_SOURCE` at the very start of your fat32.c source file.
3. Continue to use `c99` mode and add `-D_DEFAULT_SOURCE` to your compiler arguments.